# How can I see which line is the longest in a document using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How can I see which line is the longest in a document using Notepad++?

The document contains over 500,000 lines so it's inconvenient to scroll to look for it manually.

Comment: Why would you do this, when there much more appropriate tools?

Comment: @StephenRauch Get to know whether it is possible with Notepad++  as I often use it to open text documents. If you are aware of more appropriate tools though, I am interested: [Finding the longest line of a document](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38934/903)

Comment: I stand corrected.  Notepad++ has a python interface.  Who Knew?

Comment: @StephenRauch I knew about the Notepad++ Python interface, etc. with the Python Plug-ins. I didn't know until about a year or so ago though but Notepad++ seems rather robust and Open Source -- Good free software for Windows for sure. +1

Answer (score 6):

To find the longest line in a file using Notepad++ 32-bit.

1. Install the python plugin. To do so:

   1. From the menu, select *Plugins→Plugin Manager→Show Plugin Manager*
   2. Check the box for *Python Script* and click on *Install*
2. Create a new script: From the menu, select *Plugins→Python Script→New Script*
3. Name the script `Longest Line` and select *Save*
4. Paste the text below into the editor and save the file
5. From the menu, select *Plugins→Python Script→Scripts→Longest Line*

---

```
from Npp import *
import re

longest_line = (-1, -1, -1)

editorContent = editor.getText()
position = 0
eol_size = 2 if editor.getEOLMode() == 0 else 1
for line_number, line in enumerate(editorContent.splitlines()):
  if len(line) > longest_line[1]:
    longest_line = line_number+1, len(line), position
  position += len(line) + eol_size

editor.setCurrentPos(longest_line[2])

notepad.messageBox("Longest line is line number %d @ %d characters" % longest_line[:2])
```

Comment: Question: Isn't it possible to avoid that ugly underscore (_) character and call the script "Longest File.py"? Personally, I hate underscore.

Comment: @FleetCommand, Excellent Suggestion...  done.

Comment: This saved my day !! Thanks

Comment: @JeyaSuriyaMuthumari, glad it could help.